# What is the argument to save a png image into grayscales?

Tags: c++, image-processing, libpng

I actually use the libpng to save png images.
To configure the library, I'm using the following line : `png_set_IHDR(png, info, width, height, 8, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);`
What is the right argument to replace `PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB` to save a png image into grayscales ?
(color type 0)
Thanks !

Comment: Maybe `PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY`

Comment: I want to save a monochrome image and I don't know how I can make it.

Comment: @drescherjm I will try it !

Comment: But what should I write for a monochrome image with an alpha channel ?

Comment: This is explained in the documentation. http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.2.5-manual.html#section-3.5

Comment: Thanks ! This is `PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY_ALPHA`.